# Java Libraries Runtime vs Compile Time

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When setting up a Java web application using Tomcat as an application server I often get confused about when libraries are available.  Through some discussion on Stack Overflow, I have learned that some libraries (.jar) files are available at runtime, while others are available at compile time.  Often I will get errors and will resolve them by trial and error, placing jar files in different directories until the application runs or compiles.  It was recently pointed out to me that you can make .jar libraries available at runtime via the WEB-INF/lib folder.  I started thinking about this and had a few question.  I have read up on this topic in the past and haven't found a source that puts the information into a context I easily understand and retain.

1. Is there a compile time classpath and a runtime classpath you can set for a project?

   a.  Is classpath even an applicable term for discussing libraries available at runtime?
2. Is WEB-INF/lib the only way to make libraries available at runtime?  What about the lib folder in Tomcat is this available at runtime?
3. How does this relate to classloaders?  I know that a hierarchy of classloaders is created.  Are these strictly for Runtime operations?

Comment: "Is there a compile time classpath and a runtime classpath you can set for a project?" I don't think  a "project" is a Tomcat concept. Are you  thinking of a webapp or a Eclipse (or other IDE) project?

Comment: I should have scoped this better, I'm taking Eclipse and Tomcat into account.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The compile classpath is the classpath used to compile your Java source files (using `javac -cp ...`, or your IDE). Every class referenced in the source file must be present in the compile classpath, else the compiler will complain that it can't find the class.

Once you have compiled the classes, you can run a program using them (using `java -cp ...`). Obviously, the libraries on which your source code depends directly should be in the runtime classpath. But that's not all. If you depend directly on CoolLibrary.jar, and this library internally depends on Guava.jar, then Guava.jar must also be in the runtime classpath, although it was not needed when compiling.

Webapps are a bit special. The servlet specification specifies that the classpath used to execute the webapp is composed by the WEB-INF/classes directory of the deployed webapp, and of all the jars contained in WEB-INF/lib. All the webapps also have access to the native servlet and JSP jars, which are directly provided by Tomcat. In reality, Tomcat's internal classes (like the implementation classes of the servlet-api interfaces) are also available to the webapp, but relying on these classes is not a good idea, since it would tie your webapp to tomcat.

Talking of the runtime classpath, in the case of a webapp, is a bit of a simplification. In reality, every webapp's classes are loaded dynamically by a specific classloader by tomcat. And this webapp classloader is a child of the tomcat's classloader. So, in theory, you could place the webapp jars in Tomcat's classpath directly, but this would mean that all the webapps would share these libraries, and that you would have problems undeploying and redeploying webapps. The goal of having a specific classloader per webapp is to be able to have, in the same JVM, an app relying on Guava 11.0, and another one relying on Guava 12.0, for example.

For more information about tomcat classloaders, read [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

Comment: So when I open my Tomcat server in Eclipse and set its classpath that is a runtime classpath?  Is there anyway to set those per application?  I quess what I would want to avoid is a 100mb war file by specifying these jars in a runtime classpath specific to the application.

Comment: What matters is the deployed webapp. By default, all the jars under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib in the eclipse WTP project are automatically added by eclipse to the compile classpath (what Eclipse calls the build path), and are also deployed with the webapp, under WEB-INF/lib, by the Eclipse deployer. So, in a typical eclipse web project, you would put all the libraries needed by the webapp in WEB-INF/lib, and all the libraries not needed at runtime (for example, unit test libraries), in another directory, added to the build path. There is usually no reason to mess with Tomcat's internal classpath.

Answer (score 1):

1. in eclipse, you have the `java build path` which include the libraries during compile time, and you have `order and export`, which is for the runtime.
2. only the tomcat libraries available by default

Comment: On the `Order and Export` tab in Eclipse it says that `Exported entries are contributed to dependent projects` wouldn't that mean that dependent projects get those libraries for compilation?  Are you sure it relates to the server's runtime?